# pl/sql using trigger to gather queued messages in queue

Tags: oracle, triggers, queue

I am trying to work on altering an already existing queuing system... Which just gives me a headache...

The logic behind the queues is all in Oracle DB as follows:

1. Database #1 sends notifications, which are queued in Database #2 in a specific queue, let's name it Q1.
2. There is a regular job, that executes a procedure in a package (DISPATCHER), which basically is a loop that dequeues all messages in Q1 until no messages are there. Its execution is scheduled every 5 minutes, yet with the amount of queue entries it runs longer than that.
3. Dispatcher procedure distributes the messages to additional queues, from which Java processes the messages and things go further.

There isn't much control over the dispatching JOB so I decided to look up ways of making the whole framework for dispatching jobs better. I must add it is an old implementation that worked for quite a while, but most don't find it easy to control or transparent.

My point is if there are any secure ways of this dispatching process?

1. I have created a trigger on the queue table that executes a single dequeue with all the processing of the message done in DISPATCHER and it works, but i don't know if it's best the idea.
2. Looked up creating subscribers, but can't add any as it's a single-consumer queue. Considering i would have to update the framework, recreating the queue would delete all the messages that already are in the queue, which is something i'd like to omit...
3. Tried a DBMS Scheduler job to execute the DISPATCHER for more control, but it just runs "when it has resources". I'm counting on a solution that works continuously and processes the messages as fast as it can.
4. Maybe there is some more elaborate way to solve this problem, but i'm still a bit fresh and can't seem to grasp the whole advanced queuing mechanism...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you using a message queue like Oracle DBMS_AQ or RabbitMQ or Redis or anything? It's usually a lot easier to use something that's on the market already. Not having any control over the dispatching job is good; they should be loosely coupled. If you can't change anything then using DBMS_SCHEDULER is probably the way to go. Consider getting it more resources and increasing the amount of running jobs allowable.

Comment: This framework has been developed around 8 to 10 years ago... As it's a system that "works good so far" noone dared to modify it in any way. Additionally, changing this would require a lot of testing afterwards, which means a lot of time so i'm looking for a good, yet not too complicated resolution.

Comment: So, what's to stop you from increasing the number of jobs that can run and ensuring that you have one running constantly?

Comment: DBMS Scheduler job seems to be working good and i don't mind the DISPATCHER working constantly, but there are times when it needs to be turned off, i.e. when performing a deploy to the DB. For some reason it's difficult to stop the regular job and start it again with a set schedule.

I was thinking about the DBMS Scheduler job, but want to check all possible options.

Answer (score 1):

Considering constantly running job it's possible to control procedure execution by sending message through [DBMS_PIPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_pipe.htm#CHDDFCFC).
Control code sends `stop` message through dbms_pipe.
Dispatcher code runs constantly in [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI) job and checks if a `stop` message arrived in pipe.
Also it's possible to force an interrupt of DBMS_SHCEDULER job after some timeout.

Years ago I had implemented such a logic and this solution runs till now. Code below is an adapted sample which can help you to check if this approach acceptable and useful for your case.

Control package header:

```
create or replace package DispatcherControl is
  -- Package to control job state      

  procedure StartDispatcher;

  procedure StopDispatcher;

end;
```

Control package body:

```
create or replace package body DispatcherControl is

  -- User who owns dispatcher job in DBMS_SCHEDULER
  C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER    constant varchar2(100) := 'DISPATCH_USER';
  -- Main procedure to handle dispatcher requests
  C_DISPATCH_JOB_PROC         constant varchar2(100) := 'DISPATCH_USER.DISPATCHER.MAINPROC';
  -- Name for dispatch program
  C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_NAME     constant varchar2(100) := 'DISPATCH_PROGRAM';
  -- Description for dispatch program
  C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_COMMENT  constant varchar2(100) := 'Q1 dispatch task';
  -- Dispatcher job name.
  C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME         constant varchar2(100) := 'DISPATCH_JOB';
  -- Description for dispatcher job
  C_DISPATCH_JOB_COMMENT          constant varchar2(100) := 'Q1 dispatch process';
  -- Pipe name for dispatch job control.
  C_DISPATCH_PIPE_NAME        constant varchar2(100) := 'DISPATCH_CONTROL';
  -- Message text for pipe to stop dispatch job
  C_PIPE_STOP_MSG constant varchar2(100) := 'stop_dispatch';

  -- Check if DBMS_SCHEDULER program exists and create it if needed
  procedure CheckDispatcherJobExists
  is
  begin

    -- Return if program exists
    for cDummy in (
      select 1
      from all_scheduler_programs
      where
        owner = C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER and program_name = C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_NAME
        and
        rownum = 1
    ) loop
      return;
    end loop;

    -- Create disabled if not found
    sys.dbms_scheduler.create_program(
      program_name        => C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER || '.' || C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_NAME,
      program_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
      program_action      => C_DISPATCH_JOB_PROC,
      number_of_arguments => 0,
      enabled             => false,
      comments            => C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_COMMENT
    );

    -- Enable program
    sys.dbms_scheduler.enable(C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER || '.' || C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_NAME);

  end;


  -- Check status of dispatcher job and run it if not found
  procedure CheckDispatcherJobState
  is
  begin

    CheckDIspatcherJobExists;

    -- Check if job is currently running according to scheduler info
    for cDummy in (
      select * from all_scheduler_jobs
      where
        owner = C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER
    and
    job_name = C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME
    ) loop

      -- Job found, check if running
      for cDummy2 in (
        select * from all_scheduler_running_jobs
    where
    owner = C_CIS_PROGRAM_OWNER  and job_name = C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME
      ) loop

         -- Check if job really running by checking sessions list
        for cDummy3 in (
          select 1
          from
            all_scheduler_running_jobs jobs,
            sys.v_$session             sessions
          where
            jobs.owner = C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER  and jobs.job_name = C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME
            and
            sessions.sid = jobs.session_id and sessions.process = jobs.slave_os_process_id
            and
            sessions.action = jobs.job_name and sessions.username = jobs.owner
            and
            sessions.module = 'DBMS_SCHEDULER'
        ) loop

           -- Ok, return
           return;

        end loop;

        -- No process found for running job, stop and delete task before recreation
        sys.dbms_scheduler.stop_job(C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME, true);

      end loop;

      -- process found, but restart needed
      sys.dbms_scheduler.drop_job(C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME, true);

    end loop;

    -- Create one-time running job with manual start
    sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name        => C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME,
      program_name    => C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER || '.' || C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_NAME,
      enabled         => true,
      auto_drop       => true,
      start_date      => add_months(sysdate,1000),
      repeat_interval => null,
      end_date        => null,
      comments        => C_DISPATCH_JOB_COMMENT
    );

    -- Run created task
    sys.dbms_scheduler.run_job(
      job_name            => C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME,
      use_current_session => false
    );

  end;


  -- Stop and drop dispatch job.
  procedure DropDispatchJob
  is
    vSendRC integer;
  begin

    -- Send request through DBMS_PIPE and wait for timeout.
    sys.dbms_pipe.reset_buffer;
    sys.dbms_pipe.pack_message(C_PIPE_STOP_MSG);
    vSendRC := sys.dbms_pipe.send_message(C_DISPATCH_PIPE_NAME,1);
    if(vSendRC = 0) then
      -- wait if sent Ok
      sys.dbms_lock.sleep(0.25);
    end if;

    -- force job stop (not done in case of drop_job)
    for cDummy in (
      select 1 from all_scheduler_running_jobs
      where
        owner = C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER
        and
        job_name = C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME
    ) loop

      begin
        sys.dbms_scheduler.stop_job(C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME, true);
      exception
        when others then begin
          -- If sqlcode = -27366 then task finished, in other case it's unexpected
          if(SQLCODE != -27366) then
            raise;
          end if;
        end;
      end;

    end loop;

    -- delete job if exists, allow stopping
    for cDummy in (
      select 1 from all_scheduler_jobs
      where
        owner = C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER
        and
        job_name = C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME
    ) loop

      sys.dbms_scheduler.drop_job(C_DISPATCH_JOB_NAME, true);

    end loop;

    -- drop program if exists
    for cDummy in (
      select 1 from all_scheduler_programs
        where
          owner = C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_OWNER
          and
          program_name = C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_NAME
    ) loop

      sys.dbms_scheduler.drop_program(C_DISPATCH_PROGRAM_NAME, true);

    end loop;

    -- Clear DBMS_PIPE messages after job stop (cover case of forced stop).
    sys.dbms_pipe.purge(C_DISPATCH_PIPE_NAME);

  end;

  -- Start dispatcher process
  procedure StartDispatcher
  is
  begin

    -- Clear message queue before starting
    sys.dbms_pipe.purge(C_DISPATCH_PIPE_NAME);

    CheckDispatchJobState;

  end;

  -- Stop dispatcher process
  procedure StopDispatcher
  is
  begin
    DropDispatchJob;
  end;

end;
```

Dispatcher package header:

```
create or replace package DISPATCH_USER.Dispatcher is

  -- Main queue check procedure to run from job.
  procedure MainProc;

end;
```

Dispatcher package body:

```
create or replace package body DISPATCH_USER.Dispatcher is

  -- Normal wait time in seconds
  NORMAL_CHECK_INTERVAL constant number := 0.01;

  -- Checks if stop message received.
  function CheckIsStopped return boolean
  is
   vPipeRC integer;
   vMsg    varchar2(1024);
  begin
    -- check if message exists
    vPipeRC := sys.dbms_pipe.receive_message('DISPATCH_CONTROL',0);
    if(vPipeRC = 0) then
      -- check type of message content, must be varchar2 (look for constants in sys.dbms_pipe package).
      if(sys.dbms_pipe.next_item_type = 9) then

        -- check message content
        sys.dbms_pipe.unpack_message(vMsg);
        if(vMsg = 'stop') then
          return true;
        end if;

      end if;

    end if;

    return false;

  end;


  -- Checks if error caused by external interrupt
  function IsInterruptError(piSQLCode in number) return boolean
  is
  begin

    if( piSQLCode in (

          -1013,  -- ORA-01013: User requested cancel of current operation
          -28,    -- ORA-00028: Your session has been killed
          -13638, -- ORA-13638: The user interrupted the current operation
          -13639, -- ORA-13639: The current operation was interrupted because it timed out.
          -13668, -- ORA-13668: The current operation was aborted because it was blocking another session
          -48223, -- ORA-48223: Interrupt Requested - Fetch Aborted - Return Code [string] [string]
          -48495  -- ORA-48495: Interrupt requested

        )
      ) then

      return true;

    end if;

    return false;

  end;

  -- Main procedure for dispatcher job
  procedure MainProc
  is
    vIsFound       boolean;
    vSQLCode       number;
    vErrMsg        varchar2(2048);
    vCheckInterval number;
    vMESSAGE       SOME_CUSTOM_MESSAGE_DATA_TYPE;  -- Just for example
  begin

    vCheckInterval := NORMAL_CHECK_INTERVAL;

    while(true) loop

      vIsFound := false;

      begin

        vMESSAGE := GET_NEXT_MESSAGE_FROM_QUEUE; -- Just for example

        if(vMESSAGE is not null) then

          vIsFound := true;

          -- Process received message her
          DISPATCH_MESSAGE(vMESSAGE);  -- Just for example

          -- Commit changes to save a redo log from overflow.
          commit;

        end if;

      exception
        when others then begin

          vSQLCode := SQLCODE;
          vErrMsg := SQLERRM;

          if( IsInterruptError(vSQLCode) ) then
            -- Promote error if interrupted forcibly
            raise;
          end if;

          -- In other cases just write error conditions to log and continue.
          -- Log writing totally skipped from this example, so only comment here.

          -- Also it's a place to perform extra error analysis. 
          -- E.g. if it is some temporary error caused by remote database shutdown
          -- and so on, then increase vCheckInterval and don't stress server.

        end;
      end;

      -- Check if interrupted programmatically from control procedure
      if( CheckIsStopped ) then
        -- normal exit, job finished
        return;
      end if;

      -- If there are no new request then put process in sleep state
      -- for a short time to release resources
      if(not vIsFound) then
        dbms_lock.sleep(vCheckInterval);
      end if;

    end loop;

    -- This point never reached
    null;

  end;

end;
```

Please note, that code above is a simplified example (e.g. no logging of performed activity). Also, example code adopted to match question conditions and contain some assumptions like Oracle user names and generics like GET_NEXT_MESSAGE_FROM_QUEUE. Please feel free to ask if  something not clear in example code.